# PhantomJS and Karma Jasmine tests Linux error

Tags: continuous-integration, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have problems with my Karma tests. I run them as usual:

`node_modules/karma/bin/karma start test/karma.conf.coffee`

Then I got:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.9.8 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket id sdxrDmAhioK5PjzAMy1O
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) ERROR               
        Script error.
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) ERROR               
        Script error.
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) ERROR               
        Script error.
```

and on Ubuntu:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.9.8 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux)]: Connected on socket id kTXPYWO4-nCqsKK8Pb5m
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux) ERROR
  Script error.
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux) ERROR
  Script error.
```

The most interesting is that on Mac I almost always get

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X): Executed 185 of 185 SUCCESS (3.242 secs / 2.381 secs)
```

and on linux the it looks similar in development environment. Unfortunately when I run tests on CI (codeship.io) tests always fail. It happens only recently, because when I got up to 150 tests, everything was going OK.

What am I doing wrong? Can I set some kind of timeout for PhantomJS?

Comment: I am too getting this same error. Please help us to solve our problem.

Comment: The error occurred because `Pusher` library wasn't mocked properly and causes connection to external server.

Comment: I got the same error but I don't use Pusher :/

Comment: Make sure you stub all HTTP connections.